# Can we get all of the private views in a SharePoint list using rest api

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint-2013

> Is there a way to get all private views in a SharePoint list
>   using Rest API or JSOM.
>
> I'm trying below endpoint but it is returning all of the views:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Custom List')/views
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get all private views in a list:

```
http://sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('csutom list')/views?$filter=PersonalView eq true
```

A demo:
[image]